# Error while installing PyCaret in GCP's JupyterLab

Tags: gcp-ai-platform-notebook, pycaret

I am trying to install PyCaret in GCP(Google Cloud Platform) JupyterLab. I am getting error while installing the PyCaret package.

I was using [`!pip install pycaret`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwGwH.png) to install the package but I was getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o831k.png).

> ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'llvmlite'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Then I have used [`!pip install pycaret --ignore-installed llvmlite`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmqEQ.jpg)
But then I was getting [these other errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRSjq.png).

But even after these errors when I tried to [import different modules from PyCaret library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taSf9.png), I was able to do so. Please let me know if anyone is aware that :

1. Why I am getting these errors in GCP's JupyterLab ? It seems to me that it is
   trying to install older version of tensor flow, I do not know why it is doing
   that if that is true.
2. How can I remove this error ?
3. If I am getting the error while installing the package then how I am able to
   successfully import the modules from it ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error only means that based on the environment that you are running the install in, there is incompatibility between what pycaret is asking for and what is already installed based on other packages. Even with these warnings, pycaret may still run because at least some version of the required libraries are installed.

My recommendation would be to install pycaret in a clean environment. That way, there is no interference with other packages.